# Create a matrix with conditional sum in each row -R

Tags: r, matrix

I've created this matrix:

```
> atr <- matrix(rnorm(18,50,3), nrow=9, ncol=2) 
> atr
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,] 49.1 46.3
 [2,] 49.9 49.2
 [3,] 52.3 51.6
 [4,] 49.3 46.1
 [5,] 54.3 51.8
 [6,] 46.7 47.2
 [7,] 46.6 57.6
 [8,] 53.9 53.4
 [9,] 46.6 53.1
```

How Can I create the same matrix with values equal to rnorm(18,50,3) but with the condition that the sum of values on each row must be less or equal than 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
nrow <- 9
ncol <- 2
mat <- matrix(nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
i <- 1
while (i <= nrow) {
    x <- rnorm(ncol, mean = 50, sd = 3)
    if (sum(x) <= 100) {
        mat[i, ] <- x
        i <- i + 1
    }
}
```